# Exit a userform if user choose not to input anything

Tags: excel, userform, commandbutton

I only have a RefEdit control and a command button on a userform.

[image]

This is the desired scenario:

[ If the user after activating the userform, 
decided not to select any cell range and 
he just press enter, 
**the userform should just close**. ]

What is the code to accomplish the above which I can put into the **Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()**?

Thank you.

Additional note:
I know the user can just click the big red X at the top right corner of the userform to close it. In my case, the user does not want to use the mouse. He is a very keyboard-centric Excel user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If RefEdit1.Text = "" Then
        Unload Me
    Else
        MsgBox "Do your Thing"
    End If
End Sub
```